# Including Row ID from MySQL Table in Android ListView (for each list item)

Tags: android, database, android-listview, rowid

When I grab info from a database (I am using `MySQL`), I'd like to also grab the `id` of the row and somehow assign it to each row of the 'listView`.

For example, let's say there is a table called `fruit`.  `fruit_id` of 16 is `orange`.  When the `listView` displays the list of fruit, and user clicks on a row that shows orange, i'd like to be able to access the `fruit_id`(16) of that row.  But I'm not sure where to "hide" it.

Doing some initial research it seems there are multiple ways one can do this.  The simplest might be something with using a `tag`, is this the best way? if so, how can you assign an `id` to it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `class` named Fruit.

```
class Fruit {
    private int fruit_id;
    private String fruit_name;

    // Constructors

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Use an `ArrayAdapter<Fruit>` as the `ListAdapter` for your `ListView`. Then at `ListView`'s `onItemClickListener`, get the Fruit object and get its id.

Comment: I am already doing this exact method actually... so, I retrieve the id in my getView method in the Adapter... but.. what do I _do_ with it?  That was my main question.  How do I assign it (not as a UI element) to the row?

Comment: Actually when you assign the `ArrayAdapter<Fruit>` as `ListAdapter`, the Fruit objects are automatically assigned to corresponding `ListView` item. In the `onItemClickAdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id` method, you retrieve the id using `((Fruit) mAdapter.getItem(position)).getId()`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an `ArrayAdapter` to back your `ListView`, then @jaibatrik's suggestion is definitely a good one. However, if you're using a `CursorAdapter`, it's probably easier to exploit the return value of [`getItemId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId%28int%29).

By default, a `CursorAdapter` will look for a column with the name `"_id"` in the `Cursor` you supply it and return that as `id` value whenever you click an item:

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

That last value will contain the id of your cursor item. You can also override this behaviour and have it return any other unique value you may have access to in the `Cursor`.

The same is also true for an `ArrayAdapter`: by default it will return the position of the item in the array as unique id. However, you could easily make it return `fruit_id` for every item by overriding that method. Then it'll be passed in the `onItemClick(...)` directly, which saves you retrieving it (again) in there.

---

> My questions is, if I grab, for example, item_id (not just item),
>   where do I put item_id in the listView rows (on Android side)?

The beauty of having objects that represent the data you're visualising in the list, is that you already have all the ingredients to make it work. Let's take the `Fruit` example given by @jaibatrik and add one getter for the sake of this example:

```
class Fruit {
    private int fruit_id;
    private String fruit_name;

    // Constructors

    // Getters and Setters
    public int getId() { return fruit_id; }
}
```

In the comments you're describing you retrieve the fruit data from the database and populate it in a list:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = ...
```

That list should be the dataset backing your `ArrayAdapter`. To be more specific, since it's a typed class, you should have an `ArrayAdapter<Fruit>` instance that you set as adapter to the `ListView`.

Now, assuming you have an `OnItemClickListener` set against the `ListView`, it will fire whenever the user taps on an item. Using the parameters passed into the callback, you can retrieve the item that is associated with the position that was selected:

```
@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Fruit fruit = (Fruit) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    int fruit_id = fruit.getId();
    ...
}
```

With the object retrieved, you can do anything you like with the data it holds. No need to explicitly set the id against the row views, since it should already be part of the dataset that backs the `ListView`.

Comment: I am using ArrayAdapter.   But my question remains, where do I store the id?

Comment: @KickingLettuce: Based on your other comment, you already have some sort of simple object to encapsulate the row data. Your `ArrayAdapter` should be associating these data objects with views based on a 'position'. That same 'position' gets passed in whenever the user taps on a row, which allows you to retrieve the whole object from either the `ListView` or its `Adapter`. In other words: as far as I can tell, **you're already storing the id**, so I'm a little unsure as to what isn't clear to you? Perhaps it's a good idea to share some code in your question to pinpoint the exact problem?

Comment: I don't have code as of yet.  I am looking to store the row id from MySQL.  I pass that in through a `AsyncTask` where I grab the items from the table I want and put them into the object in the `onPostExecute()`.  My questions is, if I grab, for example, item_id (not just item), where do I put item_id in the listView rows (on Android side)?  I need these for example, so I can pass back into Databse if I want to delete or edit info on that row.

Comment: @KickingLettuce: I've made an addition to my answer that should hopefully explain that you shouldn't have to set the id explicitly against the row views if you're using a proper dataset as backend for the adapter/listview.